# C for loop implemented differently than other languages?

Tags: c++, c, knuth

I read the following in a review of Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming":

"The very 'practicality' means that the would-be CS major has to learn Kernighan's mistakes in designing C, notably the infamous fact that a for loop evaluates the for condition repeatedly, which duplicates while and fails to match the behavior of most other languages which implement a for loop."

(http://www.amazon.com/review/R9OVJAJQCP78N/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R9OVJAJQCP78N)

What is this guy talking about?  How could you implement a for loop that wasn't just syntactic sugar for a while loop?

Comment: Just added the C++ tag, since the answer to this question is at least as relevant in C++ (typical usage pattern: for (iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i) //... )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider this:

```
for i:=0 to 100 do { ... }
```

In this case, we could replace the final value, 100, by a function call:

```
for i:=0 to final_value() do { ... }
```

... and the `final_value`-function would be called only once.

In C, however:

```
for (int i=0; i<final_value(); ++i) // ...
```

... the `final_value`-function would be called for each iteration through the loop, thus making it a good practice to be more verbose:

```
int end = final_value();
for (int i=0; i<end; ++i) // ...
```

Comment: I don't agree. How do you know the value of final_value() isn't going to return a different value each time? If final_value() only returns a constant then most compilers will optimize this as you say, but it won't always be the case.

Comment: For this example I assume that you actually only want to call final_value once. This is cumbersome to express in C.

It might very well be that you want final_value to be called every time, but most often I find that I only want it called once.

Comment: @Tarski: and the compile cannot optimize away the call to final_value(), because it cannot know if the return value is stable.  Consider "for(i=0; i<strlen(str); ++i)"  Now, you may or may not be changing the length of str in your loop, (but 99.99% of the time, you won't be)

Comment: Compiler will optimize it away if final_value() lives in the same source file as the loop.

Comment: @Jim: You're making assumptions about the complexity of final_falue() and how much the optimizer can/will do.  Some optimizers cross compilation units, others are limited even within one source file.

Comment: Sorry. What I said was incorrect. There will be cases where the compiler will optimize this. Like if final_value() is hardcoded to return 5, and is in the same source file, but also cases where it cannot - so how are other languages any different? like the equivalent of strlen in PASCAL?

Comment: @Tarski: In Pascal, final_value would be called exactly once because this is the semantics of the for-loop in this language. It is not even considered an optimization. :) (Also, the equivalent of strlen is O(1) in Pascal ;)

Comment: @Tarski that Optimization can only happen if the compiler can actually tell the function always returns the same thing... that's frequently not the case.

Comment: @James that one the compiler probably will optimize since it probably knows what strlen does.

Comment: @spudd86 - that's doubtful, as the compiler would also have to track what happens to the string being measured.  Also, it's legal to write your own function called strlen which does something completely different.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is a simple counting loop, then

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) dostuff();
```

will be fine, and the compiler can optimize it.

If you use a function in the continue part of the for statement, like

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) dostuff();
```

then the function will be evaluated every time and this is usually not a good idea as the function overheads will slow your process. Sometimes it can slow your process to the point of unusability.

If the function's return value will not change during the iteration, extract it from the loop:

```
slen = strlen(s);
for (i=0; i<slen; i++) dostuff();
```

But there are times when the function will be returning different values each call, and then you do not want it extracted from the loop:

```
for (isread(fd, &buffer, ISFIRST);
     isstat(fd) >= 0;
     isread(fd, &buffer, ISNEXT)
{
  dostuff(buffer);
}
```

and you want it evaluated each time. (That is a slightly contrived example based on work that I do, but it shows the potential).

C gives you the raw ability to roll your loop any way you can. You have to know how your loop is supposed to work, and you optimize it as best you can, depending on your needs.

That last example could have been expressed as a while loop:

```
isread(fd, &buffer, ISFIRST);
while (isstat(fd) >= 0)
{
  dostuff(buffer);
  isread(fd, &buffer, ISNEXT);
}
```

but it's not as neat, and if I use a continue in the loop, then I have to call the iterating isread again. Putting the whole thing in a for loop makes it neater, and ensures that the iterating isread is called each loop.

I write lower-level functions so they can be used in for loops like this. It brings all elements of the while loop together so you can understand it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

He probably refers to for loops like `for i:=0 to N` and for-each loops that iterate over the elements of a set. I suspect all languages that have a C-style for loop actually got it from C.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  TAOCP and K&R are both *old*.  A lot of languages have inherited from C since then.

Comment: Plus one. For example, BASIC For loops.

Answer (score 3):

Magnus has it right, but one should also note that in most languages (pre-C), the conditional is the *end* criterion (i.e. "stop when i equals 100").  In C (and most post-C languages), it's the *continue* criterion (i.e., "continue while i is less than 100").

Comment: but how could you know when i was 100 unless you evaluated it after each loop iteration?

Comment: I'm merely talking syntax, not evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Loop unrolling perhaps? If you know how many time the for loop is going to execute you can literally copy and paste the contents of the loop. Most while loops are going to be be based on some condition that isn't a simple counting from 0 to N, so won't be able to use this optimization.

Take this example

```
int x;
for (x = 10; x != 0; --x)
{
    printf ("Hello\n");
}
```

I know you would normally do `x = 0; x <= 10; ++x`, but all will be revealed in the assembly.

some pseudo assembly:

```
mov 10, eax
loop:
print "hello"
dec eax
jne loop
```

In this example we keep jumping back around the loop to print "hello" 10 times. However we are evaluating the condition with the `jne` instruction each time around the loop.

If we unrolled it we could simply put

```
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
print "hello"
```

We wouldn't need any of the other instructions, so it is faster. This is only a simple example - I'll try to find a better one!

Comment: You mean it *could* be faster? The larger code size could lead to L1/L2 cache misses which then could result in slower code.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the C (and Java, JavaScript, and lot of C-derived languages) `for` loop is indeed syntactic sugar for a `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) { DoStuff(); }
```

which is a very current idiom is strictly equivalent to:

```
int i = 0; while (i < max) { DoStuff(); i++; }
```

(Putting apart scope issues, which changed between versions of C anyway.)

The stop condition is evaluated on each iteration. It can be interesting in some cases, but it can be a pitfall: I saw `i < strlen(longConstantString)` in a source, which is a major way to slow down a program, because `strlen` is a costly function in C.
Somehow, the `for` loop is mostly designed to run a number of times know in advance, you can still use `break` to terminate early, so the dynamic evaluation of the stop term is more annoying than useful: if you really need dynamic evaluation, you use `while () {}` (or `do {} while ()`).

On some other languages, like Lua, the stop condition is evaluated only once, at loop init. It helps predicting loop behavior and it is often more performant.

Comment: strlen is special since at least GCC knows it can optimize it away in certain cases. (It's a "pure" function since it always return the same output if its given the same input).

Comment: Your max variable is badly named, better to call it count since the loop won't be executed with i = max.

Comment: The stop *value* is evaluated only once. The stop *condition* has to be evaluated each time in the loop to determine whether to stop or not. The difference is that in C/C++, you specify the stop condition directly, and the condition can be whatever you want. However, there is no stop value that could potentially be computed only once.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't understand your last sentence, and disagree with your first one... In C, the stop value is computed on each loop. And the stop condition too, of course.

Comment: @PhiLho: Think of the loop condition as "<loop variable> <operator> <stop value>" (so in `i < 5`, `i` is the loop variable, less than is the operator and 5 is the stop value). In every language, the loop *condition* is evaluated every loop. Otherwise, it would be impossible to loop twice. The issue is how many times the stop *value* is evaluated. And C/C++ don't have a language concept of a stop value. In the C/C++ for loop, `i` can be the loop variable and the condition can be `foo<bar`. There need not be a stop value, so there is nothing for the language to specify is evaluated once.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: the loop condition can have any form that returns something equivalent to a boolean. It can be `foo() && bar()`, `RADIUS > dist(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, `answer == IGNORE` or whatever. There is not really a _stop value_, indeed, except the result of evaluating the stop condition, but _you_ introduced the concept, so I don't see the point of this discussion. Ah, or perhaps you are contesting my last sentence in my answer, which is indeed a bit ambiguous... :-)

Comment: My point is that *every* language evaluates the stop condition every loop. The difference between C and languages that have something that they evaluate once is that those other languages have a stop value and C doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

On x86, for looping can be done on assembly level without making a while loop. The **loop** instruction decreases the value of the register ecx and jumps to the operand if ecx is greater than 0, it does nothing otherwise. This is a classic for loop.

```
mov ecx, 0x00000010h
loop_start:
;loop body
loop loop_start
;end of loop
```

Comment: Assembler doesn't really count here.

Comment: This is why some will tell you to loop backwards if possible, i.e. for(i=limit; i>0; i--) {whatever;}.  Writing it that way can allow the compiler to make this optimization in the binary.

Comment: If the compiler can prove that each loop iteration is independent of the next, it can make this optimization on its own.  I'd say that it's perfectly acceptable to bring assembly into this discussion since C is often called "cross platform assembly".

Answer (score 2):

In Ada (and I believe most other Algol-derived languages) the terminating condition of a "for" loop is evaluated only once, at the beginning of the loop. For example, suppose you have the following code in Ada

```
q := 10;
for i in 1..q loop
    q := 20;
    --// Do some stuff
end loop;
```

This loop will iterate exactly 10 times, because q was 10 when the loop started. However, if I write the seemingly equivalent loop in C:

```
q = 10;
for (int i=0;i<q;i++) {
   q = 20;
   // Do some stuff
}
```

Then the loop iterates 20 times, because q was changed to 20 by the time i got large enough for it to matter.

The C way is more flexible, of course. However this has quite a few negative implications. The obvious is that the program has to waste effort rechecking the loop condition every cycle. A good optimizer might be smart enough to work around the problem in simple cases like this, but what happens if "q" is a global and "do some stuff" includes a procedure call (and thus in theory could modify q)?

The hard fact is that we just know *way* more about the Ada loop than we do about the C loop. That means that with the same level of intelligence and effort in its optimizer, Ada can do a lot better job of optimizing. For instance, the Ada compiler knows that it can replace the entire loop with 10 copies of the contents, no matter what those contents are. A C optimizer would have to examine and analyze the contents.

This is actually just one of many ways where the design of the C syntax hamstrings the compiler.

Comment: Actually, the condition has to be evaluated *every* time. If the condition was only evaluated once, it would either be true or false, and the loop would either loop forever or only once. The difference between C and Ada is that in C, you specify a terminating condition while in Ada, you specify a terminating value. In both cases, the condition is evaluated each time in the loop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - There's a difference between checking to see if a loop is done, and having to go recheck this iteration's value for `q` in preparation for checking to see if the loop is done. Repace `q` with a calcuation or a function call, and perhaps you see the problem. Also note that there in fact would be *no* calculation every iteration if the loop is unrolled, which the Ada compiler above could trivially do, but the C compiler might not be able to, depending on what's in "Do some stuff".

Answer (score 1):

What these language purist never seem to realize is the whole point of C, and to an extent C++, is giving the possibility to implement what you want and how you want it. Now admittedly if the result of your end expression changes, it would be better to just use a while loop. Maybe the problem is programmers get the impression C implements a "high level" for, but everyone should know C is a pretty low-level language.

Answer (score 1):

> > The very 'practicality' means that the would-be CS major has to learn Kernighan's mistakes in designing C, notably the infamous fact that a for loop evaluates the for condition repeatedly, which duplicates while and fails to match the behavior of most other languages which implement a for loop.

*Muaahahahaa!*

I like the basic (pun intented) assertions of the reviewer:

- Kernighan's mistakes
- infamous fact
- fails to match the behavior of most other languages

For me, it smells of someone who never succeeded mastering C's basic features/philosphy.

### Introduction

As I was still studying physics in university, I found C (i.e. C-like languages) were to become my language of choice when I discovered C's **for** loop.

So apparently, one's style failure is another's style success. This will end the subjective part of this discussion.

### Perhaps Kernigan's for should have been called loop?

Just kidding? Perhaps not.

The author of the review apparently decided that each language construct should have the same behavior across languages. So renaming **for** as **loop** would have eased his/her discomfort.

The problem is that the author fails to understand that C's **for** is an extension of **while**, not a different loop. This means **while** is a syntactic sugar light version of **for**, instead of the **while** other languages where **for** may have been castrated down.

### Is C for really needed?

Quoting the author of the review, he/she makes the following assertions about **for** and **while**:

- **for** is for constant loops, from a beginning to an end
- **while** is for loops evaluating a condition at each iteration

Having orthogonal features is a good thing when you can combine them. But in all languages I know, there is no way to combine both **for** and **while** together.

Example: What if, for the reviewer's language, you need a loop going from a beginning to an end (like a **for**), but still able to evaluate at each loop iteration (like a **while**): You could need to find in a subset of a container (not the whole container), a value according to some stateful test?

In a C-like language, you use the **for**. In the reviewer's ideal language, you just, well, hack some ugly code, crying because you don't have a **for_while** loop (or C's **for** loop).

### Conclusion

I believe we can summarize the reviewer's critic of C (and C-like languages) with the following statement "*Kernigan's infamous mistake of not giving C the syntax of the previous, existing languages*", which can be summarized again as "*Never think different*".

Quoting Bjarne Stroustrup:

> > There are only two kinds of languages: the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses.

So, all in all, the reviewer's comment should be considered as a praise.

^_^

Comment: Incidentally, the Go programming language only has the `for` loop with a special case when only one statement is provided in the loop's head in which case it behaves like a `while` in C.

Comment: I was gonna vote you up right up to the point where you cited the devil..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Knuth is referring to BASIC.

In BASIC (the older one, I dont know about VB), FOR loops were implemented differently.

E.g.  to loop ten times

FOR N=1 TO 10

...

NEXT N

---- OR ----
to find sum of even numbers below 100

FOR N=0 TO 100 STEP 2

...

NEXT N

In C, you may have any condition in "for" to check for exiting the loop.  More flexible, I think.